Signet mobile phone wallet
I have been using Testnet with bitcoin core and mobile wallets from Bitpay and copay using a testnet wallet.  Testnet is currently broken, and I need an alternative.  I have discovered Signet, and have a bitcoin core running Testnet I could convert to signet.  However, I need to be able to send and receive Signet using a mobile phone.  I know I need Internet access, so I plan to move to AWS to make it more universally available.  The question I have is this:  Will existing mobile phone test net wallets work with SigNet?  Can Signet coins coexist with Testnet? If I make a clean testnet wallet, can it receive Signet coins?

Signet and testnet are two separate blockchains. So, it is insufficient for an app to support testnet, it must explicitly support signet for you to be able to receive and send signet coins.

After asking on Twitter, I was informed that the following mobile phone apps should have signet support:

https://nunchuk.io
https://lava.xyz
https://foundation.xyz/envoy
https://www.xverse.app

I am neither recommending or endorsing any of these apps, I am just relaying this information as a starting point for your own research.
